# Передать данные: AsyncTask, WeakReference в EditText

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть activity с картой, при нажатии на карту происходит асинхронный запрос и возвращаются данные JSON. Одно из полей - адрес. Мне нужно вывести адрес в TextView. Проблема заключается в том, что когда данные приходят я их вижу в логах, но в TextView они обновятся только лишь после следующего нажатия, когда в логах появится другой адрес. Есть решение через WeakReference, но я не представляю как можно его реализовать.

```
class ParseTask(GLOBAL_POS: LatLng, GLOBAL_POS_PROVIDER: LatLng) : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

    var weakActivity: WeakReference<MapsActivity>? = null

    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String? {
        ...   
           println(GLOBAL_ADDRESS)
        ...

        return GLOBAL_ADDRESS
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        val activity = weakActivity!!.get()
        if (activity != null){
            activity.address.text = GLOBAL_ADDRESS.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Пока решение выглядит так и оно решает мою проблему, но должно быть более элегантное решение:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(600)
} catch (e: Exception) {

}
```

Получается проблема в том, чтобы присвоить значение после завершения AsyncTask. Если делать в сразу после вызова AsyncTask, то присваивается пустое значение, а в самом AsyncTask не получается привязаться к TextView.

Comment: Непонятно, это то что не работает как надо или то что не представляете как реализовать?

Comment: Мне непонятно как присвоить значение текстовому полю в другой активити после получения результата. Как это реализовать.

Comment: значение полю `weakActivity` присваиваете?

Comment: Нет, другому полю.

Comment: А как же `onPostExecute` отработает без этого?

Comment: @LyaoChin Я правильно понимаю, что Ваша `AsyncTask` запускается в одной активити, но результат работы вы хотите показать в `TextView`, которая находится в другой активити?

Comment: @Agrgg AsyncTask(отдельный класс), я вызываю (ParseTask().execute() )в MapsActivity. У MapsActivity есть activity_maps.xml - тут TextView.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja  если вам не сложно, продемонстрируйте кодом как я должен правильно реализовать это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запуск вашего `ParseTask` должен вот так выглядеть:

```
val task = ParseTask(...)
task.weakActivity = WeakActivity(instanceOfMapsActivity)
task.execute()
```

Comment: При использовании Вашей конструкции возникла проблема. у таска отсутствует weakActivity.

Comment: Пример написан исходя из кода в вопросе. Я не ясновидящий, что у вас на самом деле, не знаю.